# Intergrating facebook login into button on own login activity

Tags: java, android, facebook, authentication, android-facebook

I have a login activity within my app, the user enters an email and password and presses the login button, it then checks with a remote mysql database to see if user has entered the right details and then logins them in if they did.
I have been working on getting facebook login to integrate with my current login, I started off with this script https://gist.github.com/vishalpawale/5560725 and currently have it so the user clicks a facebook login button and is taken to the below activity:

Button code within my login:

```
fblogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FbLoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);   
            }
        });
```

FbLoginActivity:

```
public class FbLoginActivity extends Activity {

    private static List<String> permissions;
    Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fblogin);
        Button fbButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fbshare);
        /***** FB Permissions *****/
        permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
        permissions.add("email");
        /***** End FB Permissions *****/
        fbButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Check if there is any Active Session, otherwise Open New
                // Session
                Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
                if (session == null) {
                    Session.openActiveSession(FbLoginActivity.this, true,
                            statusCallback);
                } else if (!session.isOpened()) {
                    session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(
                            FbLoginActivity.this).setCallback(statusCallback)
                            .setPermissions(permissions));
                }
            }
        });
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session == null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, statusCallback,
                        savedInstanceState);
            }
            if (session == null) {
                session = new Session(this);
            }
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            session.addCallback(statusCallback);
            if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(
                        statusCallback).setPermissions(permissions));
            }
        }
    }

    private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            // Check if Session is Opened or not
            processSessionStatus(session, state, exception);
        }
    }

    public void processSessionStatus(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            if (session.getPermissions().contains("email")) {
                // Show Progress Dialog
                dialog = new ProgressDialog(FbLoginActivity.this);
                dialog.setMessage("Logging in..");
                dialog.show();
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                        new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                    Response response) {

                                if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                                if (user != null) {
                                    Map<String, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                                    GraphObject graphObject = response
                                            .getGraphObject();
                                    responseMap = graphObject.asMap();
                                    Log.i("FbLogin", "Response Map KeySet - "
                                            + responseMap.keySet());
                                    // TODO : Get Email
                                    // responseMap.get("email");
                                    String fb_id = user.getId();
                                    String email = null;
                                    String name = (String) responseMap
                                            .get("name");
                                    if (responseMap.get("email") != null) {
                                        email = responseMap.get("email")
                                                .toString();
                                        Intent i = new Intent(FbLoginActivity.this, FbLogin2Activity.class);
                                        i.putExtra("Email", email);
                                        startActivity(i);
                                    } else {
                                        // Clear all session info & ask user to
                                        // login again
                                        Session session = Session
                                                .getActiveSession();
                                        if (session != null) {
                                            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
            } else {
                session.requestNewReadPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                        FbLoginActivity.this, permissions));
            }
        }
    }

    /********** Activity Methods **********/
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d("FbLogin", "Result Code is - " + resultCode + "");
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(FbLoginActivity.this,
                requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Save current session
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Session.saveSession(session, outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Add status callback
        super.onStart();
        Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Remove callback
        super.onStop();
        Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);
    }
}
```

This works fine however it does bring up a new activity to actually login and you have to press the button on the FbLoginActivitys view before the facebook login popup shows.
What I am now trying to do is integrate the FbLoginActivity into the Login Activity so that when the fblogin button is pressed the facebook popup comes directly and their is no need to press another button.

Comment: Take the code from FBLoginActivity to your login activity where you validate within database. Then do the same on click stuff to your login button. Or, you can use this library: https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook where the login has very simple implementation

Comment: pls attach the screenshots to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way -

1. Add these vars. to your activity -

   `private static List<String> permissions;`

   `Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();`

   `ProgressDialog dialog;`
2. Copy code from `onCreate()` of `fbLoginActivity` to your activity's `onCreate()`.
3. Copy `SessionStatusCallback` & all other methods as it is, to your activity.